# Lookup function in Access to insert a result based on a text string

Tags: ms-access, vlookup, lookup-tables

I have a database that I am creating based on a loosely created spreadsheet of sales at a Print on Demand site. The details of the product that was sold is like this:
**Sale: 2009 Saturn Sky Red Line Coupe  120 - Face Mask - Adult Large - Quantity: 1**
and the next field could be:
**Sale: Hudson Hornet 4 door Sedan Twin H Power painted   - Men's T-Shirt  (Regular Fit) - Charcoal - 2XLarge - Quantity: 1**

There are many different types of product and some are quite repetitive - ie iPhone 6S case, iPhone 8 case, iPhone 10 case and so on.

I wanted to summarize what products have sold but to group them at a more consistent level - ie all iPhone cases would simply say "iPhone Case". All T-Shirts would say "T-Shirt".

So my thought was that I can do a search within these fields for *iPhone* and if the search is successful then update a new Product field with "iPhone case". If I find *T-Shirt* then I look that up and put "T-Shirt" in my new field.

I thought of putting these alternatives in a new table with the phrase to be searched in one column and the chosen result in the next column, but there are no real keys between those tables.

A very long If, then else, statement might do it as well, but much less elegantly!

Steve

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the two pieces of data supplied, they appear to be multiple pieces of data that have been combined with " - ", with data including product, product type, colour (optional), size (may be optional) and quantity.

What I'd do in this situation is to write some VBA code to process the data and to normalize it. You may need to do this in stages, dealing with the product type first, then the colour, size and product. Finally, you would add to a Sales table all of the foreign keys from these attribute tables.

The code below is what I'd start with for the product type, assuming that the data has been imported into Access in a table called `tblSalesData` in a single field, and that there is another table called `tblProductType` that has two fields, ProductTypeID and ProductType.

```
Sub sSplitSalesData()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsSales As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsProductType As DAO.Recordset
    Dim astrData() As String
    Dim intLoop1 As Integer
    Dim strSQL As String
    Set db = CurrentDb
    db.Execute "DELETE * FROM tblProductType;"
    strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT SalesData FROM tblSalesData;"
    Set rsSales = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    If Not (rsSales.BOF And rsSales.EOF) Then
        Set rsProductType = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblProductType WHERE 1=2;")
        Do
            If Left(rsSales!SalesData, 4) = "Sale" Then
                astrData = Split(Mid(rsSales!SalesData, 6), " - ")
                If IsNull(DLookup("ProductTypeID", "tblProductType", "Replace(ProductType,Chr(39),'')='" & Replace(astrData(1), "'", "") & "'")) Then
                    With rsProductType
                        .AddNew
                        !ProductType = astrData(1)
                        .Update
                    End With
                End If
                Select Case UBound(astrData)
                    Case 3  '   has product name/type/size/qty
                    Case 4  '   has product name/type/colour/size/qty
                    Case Else
                        Debug.Print "Unknown number of elements: " & rsSales!SalesData
                End Select
            Else
                Debug.Print "Odd data: " & rsSales!SalesData
            End If
            rsSales.MoveNext
        Loop Until rsSales.EOF
    End If
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rsSales.Close
    rsProductType.Close
    Set rsSales = Nothing
    Set rsProductType = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sSplitSalesData", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: Great - thanks so much. I was thinking about this as well and came up with a very similar approach (not in the code, but in the principle) and I created a second table to hold the alternative product descriptions from the loosely defined field (in fact I selected some words that always included the product) and typed in what I would like it to say. Hopefully as I go through the different variants, I will get all of them in my table!